# How to stitch several photos into a single one using Mac OS X in 360 mode or simple?

Tags: photos

Microsoft made the PhotoSynth application for iPhone but forgot to create one for OS X.

How do I stitch several photos into single one, free apps would be preferable.

Answer (score 1):

I found [Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/download/) to be the best free alternative to PhotoSynth. I only used the Windows version but they have Mac builds too.

[PTgui](http://www.ptgui.com/) is a commercial alternative to Hugin using the same core library. I remember giving it a spin and not being impressed over Hugin.

Another commercial alternative is [Autopano](http://www.kolor.com/panorama-software-autopano-pro.html) (started as a free GUI to panorama tools and went beyond that with PRO and Giga versions). I has a more polished look and feel and the Giga version is targeted at really large panoramas (think [26 gigapx](http://www.paris-26-gigapixels.com/index-en.html)).

Comment: Note that Hugin is a little hard for a beginner to use (though I'm sure people who know what they're doing can easily get great results). However, it was quite definitely the easiest free software I could find, and the one with the best results, when I last looked.

Answer (score 0):

I've become acquainted with a few models of Canon and Nikon point-and-shoot digital camera; all models in both brands came with panorama software. If your digital camera came with a software CD, you might stick it in and see what it installs.

Answer (score 0):

DoubleTake is not free but you can use the demoversion. I use it to stitch together not photos but screenshots and similar graphics. Most panorama creatings programs does not work very well with "GIF-like" graphics and typically expecting horizontal rather than vertical stitches but DoubleTake does an excellent job with that.